# drupal multisite htaccess: rewrite all languages to default language on one subsite

Tags: regex, apache, drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

- I have a Drupal 6 multisite, with 2 domains (www.example.com and www.domain.com), sharing some common content.
- The domain example.com is in three languages (EN, FR, NL). Languages are set by path prefix (/en, /fr, /nl). The other domain domain.com is just in one language (NL).
- **The problem**: on many occasions domain.com is shown in the wrong language, even if no path prefix is filled in. Somehow it seems to default to EN, though it doesn't always do that - behaviour doesn't seem to be very consistent.
- **The solution** (at least I hope): since I'm not a Drupal developer (I inhereted the site from a former colleague) I have no idea how to fix this in Drupal, so I thought the best way to fix it would be to add some rewrite rules to .htaccess.
- I'm no htaccess/regex expert either, and can't get it working. You can find my current rewrite rules below, any help or suggestions are most welcome.
- Some examples:

  - `www.domain.com/fr/some-title` needs to be rewritten to `www.domain.com/nl/some-title`
  - `www.domain.com/node/1975` needs to be rewritten to `www.domain.com/nl/node/1975`

These are the rewrite rules that were already there:

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried adding this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /nl/$1
```

and would expect this just to prepend /nl/ to all paths (thus not being a full solution since `/fr/some-title` would become `/nl/fr/some-title`) - however, a quick test shows me that:

- `/fr/some-title` is rewritten to `/nl/some-title` (which is what I need, but not what I expected)
- `/some-title` is not rewritten
- **The question**: any ideas what might be wrong? Or could this be caused by other (Drupal) settings? Or is there a better way to solve my problem?
- Just for the sake of completeness: the live website is [www.cinemazuid.be](http://www.cinemazuid.be)

Comment: In *admin/settings/language* you can set the default language. Although I don't know how this works on mulitisite. Did you check this? I suppose you added your RewriteRule *before* the other ones? (L indicates that no other RewriteRules will be executed afterwards)

Comment: @lumbric 1) /nl is set as default. 2) yes rewrite rule is *before* the rewrite rules ending by the L. 3) i don't understand your second comment :-/

Comment: Hmm, doesn't Drupal honor `Accept-Language`?

Comment: Sry, 2nd try: Something is wrong here. `/fr/some-title` is correctly rewritten to `/nl/some-title`? But before you said it would become `/nl/fr/some-title`?

Comment: @lumbric sorry, my bad - i see now that part was a bit unclear, i rephrased it a bit...

Answer (score 3):

If this rule

> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /nl/$1

is in your .htaccess file, I am surprised that it works as the leading `/` is always stripped out, so it should theoretically never match any request.

If your desire is to force a default language of **NL** for those requests that do not specify a language, then add the following rules to the top of your .htaccess file, before any existing rules

```
#if request is for existing file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
#then stop processing
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#replace fr with nl. This rule
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ /nl/$1 [L,R=301]

#if the request does not have a language of en or nl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|nl)/ [NC]
#redirect with nl as default language
RewriteRule .+ /nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If you do not want to redirect, just drop the `R=301`

I edited code above to replace `/fr/some-title` with `/nl/some-title/`.
The **L** flag tells mod_rewrite to stop processing further rules, which is usually what you want, unless you have another rule that needs to further process the current request.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. i have some questions, however: 1) it seems to be missing one element: /fr/some-title should also be rewritten to /nl/some-title/ 2) how do i integrate this into the existing rewrite rules? I was told L indicates 'last rewrite rule', and your suggestion also contains this flag?

Comment: thanks again, +1. i'm still missing some elements though (like how to integrate with the existing index.php rewrite rules). however, i've tested some extra things, and it seems like things are more complicated - even without rewrite rules some pages are redirected to /nl, others aren't. i can't afford to loose too much time on this, so I guess my best shot is to try to find a Drupal developer to have a look at it...

Answer (score 0):

```
#redirect /fr/* and /en/* to /*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(en|fr)/(.*)$ /$2 [R,L]

#internally rewrite /* to /nl/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond $1 !^nl/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nl/$1

#drupal code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```